# Turning a folder full of png icons into a PyQt4 resource?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a folder full of icons, 4.2 megabytes in total. Every single file in this folder is a png with a unique title that I want to be able to access from a single resource file. I want to put them all in an easily transportable PyQt resource file, so that I can use it on various projects for testing/packaging without having to concern myself with absolute pathnames.

Is there a straightforward way to do this using easily any tools provided by Qt/PyQt?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you want to generate a .qrc file from a folder. Am I right?

I have found two ways to accomplish this:

1. From QtCreator, create a .qrc file and when opened in the editor, select 
   *Add->Prefix, Add->Files*.
2. There is a script for this [here](https://github.com/fccoelho/qrcgen) (works recursively, too). Download qrcgen.py and use it like that: `python qrcgen.py icon-folder qrc`